# log $|f|$ is harmonics in $D$ True/false

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following statement is True /false ?

If $f$  is analytics  and nowhere  zero  in $D  =\{z : \Re z < 2019 \}$,then log $|f|$ is harmonics in $D$

my attempt : if i take $f(z)=z$ then $Log z $ is continuous at
all $z$ except those along the negative real axis. Here  im confuse that how can is  how can is  showed that log $|f|$ is harmonics in $D$?

any hints/solution

thanks u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D$ is simply connected. Hence we can write $f=e^{g}$ for some analytic function $g$. It follows that $\log|f|=\Re g$ is harmonic.

Comment: You don't need $D$ to be simply connected, since being harmonic is a local condition rather than a global one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. What you say is very true.